# Need a non-editable field in POST data, but ModelForm won't let me

Tags: django

I have a `Model` with a UUID as the pk.

```
class Product(models.Model):
    uuid = models.UUIDField(
        primary_key=True, 
        default=uuid.uuid4, 
        editable=False)
```

I need to edit some other fields using a `ModelForm` and need to submit the UUID in the POST data to identify the `Product`. At the moment, I get:

```
django.core.exceptions.FieldError: 'uuid' cannot be specified for Product model form as it is a non-editable field
```

Obviously I could make the field non-editable to quickly solve this an be done with it. However it seems to me that refusing write access to this field should occur at a lower level of logic than a `ModelForm` (i.e. I think an exception should be raised upon trying to edit it instead). Is it possible to do this instead?

Edit: sanitized traceback

```
  File "/webapps/myapp/urls.py", line 6, in <module>
    from my_app import views
  File "/webapps/myapp/views/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from .my_view import MyView
  File "/webapps/myapp/views/my_view.py", line 12, in <module>
    from my_app.forms import ProductForm
  File "/webapps/myapp/forms.py", line 5, in <module>
    class ProductForm(forms.ModelForm):
  File "/webapps/myapp/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/forms/models.py", line 242, in __new__
    opts.field_classes)
  File "/webapps/myapp/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/forms/models.py", line 138, in fields_for_model
    f.name, model.__name__)
django.core.exceptions.FieldError: 'uuid' cannot be specified for Product model form as it is a non-editable field
```

And form code:

```
class ProductForm(forms.ModelForm):
    uuid = forms.UUIDField(required=False, widget=forms.HiddenInput())
```

Comment: You need to show the actual code that is triggering that exception and the full traceback.

Comment: Ok, I've added the form code and traceback (trimmed down to make it easier to read).

Comment: I don't understand why you want the field in the form at all. As vd1 shows, to update an existing instance you pass the instance into the form, you don't need the id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specify [`instance` argument](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/forms/modelforms/#the-save-method) of form to change existing object:

```
def edit_product(request, uuid):
    product = get_object_or_404(Product, uuid=uuid)
    ...
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ProductForm(request.POST, instance=product)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            ...
```